# Login using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I faced a problem when I want to use ajax to login, but no Answer!!
the div error not show any message(success or Failed).

the html code is:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.app-framework-software.intel.com/2.0/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        function login() {

            var par = "username=" + $('#username').val() + "&password=" + $('#password').val();
            // window.alert(par); printed
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'login.php',
                data: {username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()},
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#error').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    Username:  <input type="text" id="username"/><br>
    Password  <input type="password" id="password"/><br>
    <button onclick="login()">Login</button><br>

    <label  id='error'>hh</label>
</body>
```

the login.php code above has no errors and get the result correctly but the problem in ajax code

```
       $qry = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username= '$uName' and password= '$pWord'";

       $res=mysql_query($qry);
         $checkUser=mysql_num_rows($res);
         if($checkUser > 0){
        echo "success";

        }
    else {
       echo "Failed";
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: So what have you tried debugging wise? Is your PHP getting `$uName` and `$pWord` through properly, before you send them to mysql? Echo them out before sending them to mysql. Also, `console.log(response);` and use `.done()` and and `.fail()` - the functions you are using (success) are deprecated.

Comment: first make sure that data is passed to login.php by echoing it.

Comment: What do you expect? Your js success function justs adds the ajax response to a non existing id doesn't it?

Comment: You don't sending form fields to PHP, add `name` attribute to fields e.g. `<input type="text" name="username" id="username">`. And of course you must wrap your inputs in `form` element with proper action attribute and post method. And post that fields in PHP e.g. `$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Comment: your code is working fine try in your php $uName= $_POST['username'];
$pWord= $_POST['password'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and found that it is working.

Please check the the htmlcode file and login file is present on the root at same level.

If you still face the problem then save the html file as php and then try..

Comment: before I put this question, i putted the login.html in local device and login.php in my online host.
not I upload the login.html to the same root with login.php the code work normaly.
Thank you